# Store file data to one of the array members in a structure

Tags: c++

I have a text file:

> 3 2.50 15.00 1.20
>
> 2 26.70 5.30
>
> 5 40.00 3.50 2.90 71.20 5.30
>
> 1 3.86
>
> 4 232.30 39.29 9.30 94.32

The first vertical line is number of items, followed by price for each item.

I have a structure:

```
struct Buyers
{
    int iItemCount;
    double arItemPrice[]; //array stores all items purchased by a buyer
};
```

**Questions:**

1. How to store all items prices by a buyer into array of `arItemPrice` ?

Comment: Are you asking how to read the prices from a given line (just use `>>` the appropriate number of times) or how to store data (use a `std::vector<double>` instead of an array)?

Comment: @Botje how to store data by not using vector.

Comment: This requirement should go in the question text. As per [How should I ask homework questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions), we assume no constraints and tell you to use best practices.

Comment: I'm guessing that means you cannot use `make_shared` either, then, so change the type of `arItemPrice` to `double*`, and re-read your textbook on the `new T[SIZE]` expression.  Don't forget to write a destructor that frees the memory.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a dynamic growing container, like a `std::vector` in your buyers struct.

This, because you do not know in advance, how many prices are in one line. Additionally, you need to understand that, in the text file; the count of elements is a redundant information. We can see, how many prices are in the line. And the `std::vector` does also know its size. So, the "itemCount" in your struct is also redundant.

Reading is simple by using the iostream functions. We overload the extractor operator for the Buyer struct. And in this, we first read a line and then the single elements from that line.

Please see here one of many possible solutions.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

// Define a struct for buyers. With number of prices and proces
struct Buyer {
    unsigned int itemCount{};

    // Becuase we do not know in advance, how many elements will be in the container, we use a vector
    // This can grow dynamically
    std::vector<double> itemPrice{};
};

// This will read one line of Buyer information into our Buyer struct
std::istream& operator >> (std::istream& is, Buyer& b) {

     // Read excatly one line from the stream
    if (std::string line{}; getline(is, line)) {

        // Put the string into a std::istringstream for further extraction of data
        std::istringstream iss(line);

        // Initialize our internal vector to empty
        b.itemPrice.clear();

        // Read the item count
        iss >> b.itemCount;

        // Read in a loop all prices and append them to our vector
        for (double price{}; iss >> price; b.itemPrice.push_back(price))   ;
    }
    return is;
}

// The source text file with data (is the same handling as an fstream). Like a file in memory.
std::istringstream textFile{ R"(3 2.50 15.00 1.20
2 26.70 5.30
5 40.00 3.50 2.90 71.20 5.30
1 3.86
4 232.30 39.29 9.30 94.32
)" };


int main() {
    // We will save all buyers in this  dynamically growing vector
    std::vector<Buyer> buyers{};

    // Read all byuers in a loop
    for (Buyer b{}; textFile >> b; buyers.push_back(b));

    return 0;
}
```

Added a version with `new` and without `std::vector`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

// Define a struct for buyers. With number of prices and proces
struct Buyer {
    unsigned int itemCount{};
    double* itemPrice{};

    ~Buyer() { delete[] itemPrice; }
};

// This will read one line of Buyer information into our Buyer struct
std::istream& operator >> (std::istream& is, Buyer& b) {

     // Read excatly one line from the stream
    if (std::string line{}; getline(is, line)) {

        // Put the string into a std::istringstream for further extraction of data
        std::istringstream iss(line);

        // Initialize our internal vector to empty
        b = {};

        // Read the item count
        iss >> b.itemCount;

        // Allocate new memory
        b.itemPrice = new double[b.itemCount]();

        // Read in a loop all prices and append them to our vector
        for (unsigned int i{}; i < b.itemCount; ++i)
            iss >> b.itemPrice[i];
    }
    return is;
}

// The source text file with data (is the same handling as an fstream). Like a file in memory.
std::istringstream textFile{ R"(3 2.50 15.00 1.20
2 26.70 5.30
5 40.00 3.50 2.90 71.20 5.30
1 3.86
4 232.30 39.29 9.30 94.32
)" };

int main() {
    // Use a static array with some numbers
    Buyer buyers[20];

    // Read all buyers in a loop
    unsigned int i = 0;
    while (textFile >> buyers[i] && i<20) {
        std::cout << "Line " << i + 1 << ". Count: " << buyers[i].itemCount << "\n";
        for (unsigned int k = 0; k < buyers[i].itemCount; ++k) std::cout << buyers[i].itemPrice[k] << "  ";
        std::cout << "\n";
        ++i;
    }

    // Release allocated memory
    for (unsigned int k = 0; k < i-1; ++k) {
        buyers[i].~Buyer();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hi, at first I was thinking to use vector too.. But my lecturer doesn't want us to use vector. Just a basic C++ functions and pointers and dynamic memory will do.

Comment: @Kiki: I added a additional version, without a vector